# Why can I not connect to ipvlan l2 and macvlan networks on docker?

Tags: networking, docker, linux-networking, docker-compose, docker-networking

## Macvlan

- I have tried it on several computers and VM's.
- I have tried activating promiscuous mode in all relevant computers and VM's. [Related thread by me on Super User.](https://superuser.com/questions/1806838/promiscuous-mode-capable)
- I have tried wireless and wired connections.
- I have tried assigning mac addresses manually.

Unexpected behaviour: If I don't assign mac addresses manually, I can see that the containers don't get one when I `docker inspect foo-network"`

```
version: "3.9"

services:

    nginx-pm:
        container_name: nginx-pm
        image: jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest
        volumes:
            - ./data-nginx-pm:/data
            - ./letsencrypt-nginx-pm:/etc/letsencrypt
        mac_address: 02:42:ac:11:00:10
        networks:
            prod-network:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.50.200
        ports:
            - '80:80'
            - '81:81'
            - '443:443'

networks:
    prod-network:
        name: prod-network
        driver: macvlan
        driver_opts:
            parent: wlp0s20f4
        ipam:
            config:
            -   subnet: "192.168.50.0/24"
                gateway: "192.168.50.1"
```

## Ipvlan l2

- I have tried it on several computers and VM's.

```
version: "3.9"

services:

    nginx-pm:
        container_name: nginx-pm
        image: jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest
        volumes:
            - ./data-nginx-pm:/data
            - ./letsencrypt-nginx-pm:/etc/letsencrypt
        networks:
            prod-network:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.50.200
        ports:
            - '80:80'
            - '81:81'
            - '443:443'

networks:
    prod-network:
        name: prod-network
        driver: ipvlan
        driver_opts:
            parent: wlp0s20f4
        ipam:
            config:
            -   subnet: "192.168.50.0/24"
                gateway: "192.168.50.1"
```

## Both

I have tried running commands like `ip route` from within the containers, but `which ip` shows that there is none and I cannot install the utilities.